# Software Updater showing updates for removed applications

Tags: 13.04, software-center, software-updater, adobe-acrobat

Recently, Software Updater (13.04) showed updates for Adobe Reader. Because I didn't need the application anymore, I didn't download the updates and uninstalled it (through Ubuntu Software Center). However, the updates are still showing up in the Updater (after more than a week or so). Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: test `sudo apt-get purge PACKAGENAME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to `purge` the following three packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge acroread
sudo apt-get purge acroread-bin
sudo apt-get purge acroread-common
```